# Simulate the posting of a login form to different site

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, jsp, authentication

I've been tasked with integrating a whole bunch of web sites from a switchboard-type site.  The site I am working on i'm building with asp.net using VB as the code behind.  We have one site i'm trying to pass login credentials to that i'm having trouble with.  I'm unfamiliar with how the external site was built, but was able to find a login.jsp file that has the login form.

So what I tried to do was grab the action URL from the login form of this external site and then am trying to use that URL with the login credentials added to the end of the URL string from my site.  The URL looks something like this:

http://www.oursite.com/Controller?ACTION=COMPOST&POSTMANAGER=LOGON&POSTOPERATION=LOGON&ERRORJSP=login.jsp&MANAGER=ENTRANCE&OPERATION=GETHOMEPAGE&JSP=dynamic.jsp&UserName=user1&Password=password1

I dynamically build this URL with the user credentials via the code behind and set it as the HREF for my link.

From my website when I click this link the first time it takes me to the other web site, but doesn't log me in.  However if I hit the back arrow and click on that link again then I am taken to the other web site and this time I do get logged in automatically.  Does anyone have any clue why something like this may not work the first time I hit the link, but does work the second time?

Does anyone have any other suggestions on how I might be able to handle this?  I've tried an httpwebrequest, but that doesn't redirect me to the site and I need to make sure that not only do I pass the credentials, but that the user is brought to this next site.

Thanks,
Joe

Comment: This seems like a dangerous way to go.  Isn't having the user credentials in href attributes a security flaw?  There's nothing stopping anyone from seeing them that hovers a cursor over the link, views the webpage's source, or picks up the urls using an xss vulnerability

Comment: Hi, user must be logged onto my switchboard site and have access to that specific external site to even have that link displayed, so general public can't see it.  I am currently just testing ways to get this to work before I roll it into the application.

Answer (score 0):

It might be that in the first time is tries to create a session/cookie for you and code runs too quickly to log you in. But when go back and then come back on this page the previously created cookie//session is their and it logs you in successfully

Why advice would be to check what cookies etc it create in your first step and then compare ti with you second step

Comment: Hi - I just checked and it looks as though the cookie information is the same both times clicking on the link and this is what the cookie information looks like:
Name: JSESSIONID
Value: 9460F67D47B484DD7A8E7A15639F3054
Host: www.oursite.com
Path: /
Secure: No
Expires: At End Of Session

Any suggestions on how to get this to work the first time around?

Thanks,joe